# Xamarin.iOS does not compile - CS2011 Error opening Response File

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I edited a storyboard in Xcode's Interface Builder, and assigned the View Controllers from Interface Builder.

Now when I attempt to compile the project I receive the following compiler error:

```
/absolute/path/to/project/MyProject.iOS/CSC: Error CS2011: Error opening response file '/absolute/path/to/project/MyProject.iOS/Views/Root/RootController.cs' (CS2011) (MyProject.iOS)
/absolute/path/to/project/MyProject.iOS/CSC: Error CS2011: Error opening response file '/absolute/path/to/project/MyProject.iOS/Views/Root/RootController.designer.cs' (CS2011) (MyProject.iOS)
```

I don't know if this could be related, but when I create the ViewController from Visual Studio for Mac [Community] (7.2.2 build 11) it also creates a `.xib` file for the ViewController, that I just delete as I only want the ViewController.

Anyway, is there anything I should do differently when editing storyboards from Xcode? Or is there something I'm missing when creating a new `UIViewController` from Visual Studio?

Here is the file Visual Studio generates for the `UIViewController`

```
public partial class RootController : UIViewController
{
    public RootController() : base("RootController", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to post the answer to this as I just found out what was causing it.

In my solution I have my `Views` folder named `@Views` so it sits at the top of the folder structure. Visual Studio doesn't seem to like that name `@Views` specifically the `@` and thus strips it out, which makes it an invalid path when when it goes to look for the file.

So it's my poor choice of naming that caused my own issue.